# Play Real Time from Byte array

Tags: c#, audio, audio-streaming, naudio, stm32

Im sending audio from micro to PC using dma(LAN-TCP):

```
while (1) {
      U32 max;
    int r,i;
    main_TcpNet ();     
        if(tcpSend & sendBuffer)
        {
      if(selectBuffer)
            {
                 send_datalog(ADC_RegularConvertedValueTab2,sizeof(ADC_RegularConvertedValueTab2));
               sendBuffer = 0;
            }
            else
            {   
                 send_datalog(ADC_RegularConvertedValueTab,sizeof(ADC_RegularConvertedValueTab));
               sendBuffer = 0;
            }


        main_TcpNet (); 

        }
  }
}
```

I need to play it in real time .this is what Ive done so far using NAudio:

```
         byte[] recBuff = new byte[1400];
public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
            {
                try
                {
                    SocketPacket theSockId = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;
                    int iRx = theSockId.thisSocket.EndReceive(asyn);

                    recBuff [count]= theSockId.dataBuffer[0];
                    count++;
                    if (count >= 1400)
                    {

                       //--------------------------------------------------------------------
                        for (int i = 0; i < 1400; i += 2)
                            recieveSound[i / 2] = recBuff[i] + (recBuff[i + 1] * 256);  //turn back to 16bit
                        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
                        foreach(int data in recieveSound)
                            sound.Add(data);
                        //----------------------------------
                        if (playStauts)
                        {

                                if (firstplay)
                               {




                          IWaveProvider provider = new RawSourceWaveStream(
                                                            new MemoryStream(recBuff), new WaveFormat());

                          _waveOut.Init(provider);
                          _waveOut.Play();









                                   //playThread.Start();
                                    //firstplay = false;
                               }
                           }
                        else
                        {
                            player.Stop();
                        }

                        count = 0; //RESET THE RecBuff
                    }
                     //---------------------------------------------------------------


                }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\nOnDataReceived: Socket has been closed\n");
                }
                catch (SocketException se)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
                }

            }

            private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (m_clientSocket != null)
                {
                    m_clientSocket.Close();
                    m_clientSocket = null;
                }
                Close();
            }



            private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                playThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(play));
                player = new SoundPlayer(filePath);
                toolStriplbIP.Text = "Your IP: " + GetIP();
                btnDisconnect.Enabled = false;
            }




            #region Palying Sound
            private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Array.Clear(sound, 0, sound.Count);
                    buffCount = 0;
                    offsetSound = 0;
                    sound.Clear();
                    Object objData = "7";
                    byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(objData.ToString());
                    if (m_clientSocket != null)
                        m_clientSocket.Send(byData);
                    playStauts = true;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                }
            }
            private void btnPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                playStauts = false;
            }
            #endregion

            public void play()
            {

                while(true){

                    using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(filePath))
                    {
                       //????????

                    }

                }
            }
```

I just hear like a bijilion Buzzes in sec. But When I save it and then play it I hear the song very clear and loud.
What is wrong? How can I play my byte array when its growing?

does this even work for me?

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1400];

IWaveProvider provider = new RawSourceWaveStream(
                         new MemoryStream(bytes), new WaveFormat());

_waveOut.Init(provider);
_waveOut.Play();
```

Comment: Is "ADC_RegularConvertedValueTab" a byte? or a byte array?

Comment: @Gabriel its byte as you can see here `recBuff [count]= theSockId.dataBuffer[0];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, you're using the default `WaveFormat`, which may or may not be correct.  Disagreement between source and destination formats will definitely cause you problems.

Once you're sure the `WaveFormat` is correct, I would suggest using a `BufferedWaveProvider` as the input to your wave player rather than the `MemoryStream`, something like this:

```
WaveFormat Format = new WaveFormat(/* fill in the right parameters here */);
BufferedWaveProvider Provider = new BufferedWaveProvider(Foramt);
```

Then, whenever you're happy with your `recBuff`, you just call `Provider.AddSamples` to drop the data into the `BufferedWaveProvider`, which will then be picked up by your `WaveOut` player.

There's some other strangeness going on.  Are you receiving only one byte at a time?  It looks like that's what your asynchronous handler is doing.  This might not be the best thing, since that will result in lots and lots of context switching.  If you're receiving more than one byte at a time, then you're only grabbing the first one and ignoring the rest.  That will undoubtedly result in "unexpected" sounds during playback.

Comment: Ive done this in c++.Just needed the buffer thank you